# Verifying email in database before resetting password

Tags: php, mysql, email, sql-update

Say a user of mine has entered their email into a reset password form, they get sent a email with a link that will bring them to the page above with special codes in their link

For example -

`http://mylink.com/resetpassword.php?email=blabla@gmail.com&code=2384753`

When I try to use `$_GET['email']` to get the email from the link and check it with a query it doesn't work

Here is part of my code:

```
$email = $_GET['email'];

$check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' ");

if(mysqli_num_rows($check) == 1){

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET password='$password' ");

}else{
    echo "failed 2";
}
```

But I get the `failed 2` error. and I'm pretty sure it's because when I click submit all of the extras in the link go away and its just resetpassword.php

When I turn on error reporting the following appears -

`Notice: Undefined index: email in /var/www/resetpass.php on line 6`

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: well, for one thing I hope that's not really your update statement, that will update the passwords for EVERY user in users...

Comment: Please use the MySQLi error checking methods to get the real error(s)..

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: nothing happens, I added the error reporting to the top, as soon as I hit submit it just says this:              


**Notice: Undefined index: email in /var/www/resetpass.php on line 6**

And I think it's because once you hit submit all the extras after the ? in the link go away.

Comment: @ryan2138 - Did you bother checking my answer? I've also cleaned up your answer and added some more info that you had added in the comments, see if you can get it reopened.

Comment: Can you also show us somw more part of your email sending script

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode the `@` symbol and then decode it

```
echo urlencode('blabla@gmail.com');
//outputs blabla%40gmail.com
```

You also need to realize that you're passing values directly to SQL which leaves you wide open for [SQL injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)

And finally you have to have a `WHERE` statement. In this case, I'm going to assume you've already sanitized `$email` and `$password` (you REALLY need to consider [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for that)

```
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET password='$password' WHERE email='$email' ");
```

Comment: Not to mention the UPDATE query will UPDATE **ALL PASSWORDS**

Comment: so where I send the email should I just add "urlencode('$email');? $email = to the email that the message is sent to

Comment: Yes. Encode it in the email and then `urldecode` it in your processing page

Comment: okay, but it still doesn't work. I've added urldecode('$email'); to inside the resetpass.php script (inside the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) script ). 

I also added WHERE email='$email' to the mysqli query, but now whenever I try to update the password nothing updates in the database.

Answer (score 0):

When I would suggest you do is that when the `resetpassword.php` page loads, you check if email and code are valid (via checks in the database) and then put these values inside a hidden field in the form on the `resetpassword` page.

When you are doing a `submit`, you're `$_GET` vanishes because your `form`'s action tag is just `resetpassword.php` and there are no `$_GET` variables in that action tag.